# how i use controller to rest api using in grails 2.3.1?

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I am using spring security plugin in my **grails 2.3.1** app,

I want to expose my controller as rest api,
So that mobile apps can access it.. so do i authenticate my users through my grails controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic auth over SSL is common for REST APIs, and the plugin docs show how to configure Basic auth for part of the app, and standard form-based auth for user-accessible parts of the app. There's also a new plugin for REST + Spring Security - see http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest and click through the "Documentation" button to see the docs.

Comment: @Brut : my grails project is unable resolve the dependencies for the below jar do i need to add to any additional repository "Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:jar:1.5.0

Comment: You need to add two repos in the `repositories` block - they're shown at the docs page: http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/ but I found that I also needed to add `compile 'org.pac4j:pac4j-core:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT'` in the `dependencies` block because for some reason it wasn't being transitively resolved.

Comment: @Brut: I also want to use this in a project where we are using grails and already have a web interface which uses springs security already. Now if I install the spring-security-rest plugin do I also need to change the current web application and it would start using token based authentication instead of standard http session mechanism? Also in the rest-plugin doc its mentioned this is majorly for java script clients would this work well on native mobile app? Is it standard that native mobile app would autheticate first using basic auth and then send the token with each request?